# Remote access for bash

Tags: 16.04, bash, remote-access

I am trying to look for an application that is a `bash` shell but can be remotely controlled, and instructions on how to use one.

For example, I can control it in another computer using an address, say `192.168.1.3:4567`, input username and password, and I can modify the bash shell in that address.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean something like SSH?

Comment: I'm maybe missing something, but it sounds like you're describing SSH? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

Comment: Yes. I've just searched about it.

Comment: But I want something that, for example, when I'm doing installation in my home computer (say, `apt dist-upgrade`), I want to see the progress/`stdout` in my other computer.

Comment: You want to show something to someone? On which computer you will be?

Comment: @spas-spasov I am at Computer A, and I am in a shell. I type in apt -y dist-upgrade, and there's a progress bar that shows how much the installation has progressed.

However, I am doing something else, so I go somewhere, and open Computer B. From there, I want to use an application that views the shell in Computer A, so that I can view the progress of the installer, or use, say, `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: You can do that via SSH, but I never have done it. Maybe here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410252/how-to-reuse-an-ssh-connection

Comment: It sounds like you want to run the original session within a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) such as `tmux` or `screen`, to which you should be able to attach remotely via SSH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teach me if I'm wrong but can't you archive this by running the script in a "screen" with certain name so later you can attach to this "screen" from a bash, too?

```
screen -S <screenname> apt-dist-upgrade
```

see https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Screen/

Comment: This works perfectly. I `ssh`'d my home computer then used `screen -r <screenname>`, and it shows my command progress.